# My CSV file has data 1014541696.430000072 while reading this as a dataframe I am getting output as 1014541696.43

Tags: python, pandas

I need help in getting the exact output in a dataframe as data in CSV file

File data:

```
Value
1014541696.430000072
4553059826.790000215
```

Code:

```
Import pandas as pd
Pd.options.display.float_format="{:.2f}".format

Df=pd.read_csv("file.csv")

Print(df)
```

Output from code

```
Value

1014541696.43

4553059826.79
```

**But expected output is**

```
Value
1014541696.430000072
4553059826.790000215
```

Comment: your file contains 1014541696.430000072, not 1014511696.44000000072

Comment: You very explicitly set `Pd.options.display.float_format` to only two decimal points…!?

Comment: Without explicit format getting the same output how can I get entire data

Comment: @deceze can you help me on this, I want exact output as my data contains 10 values after decimal and sometimes it's 9 or 7

Comment: If you want all of the digits, why did you set `float_format="{:.2f}"`?

Comment: Even If I won't set that the data is taking default as 2 all I need is entire output

Comment: Isn't Pandas in Python, and isn't Python case-sensitive? Does your code even compile?

Comment: Load your data as string: `pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=str)`

Comment: I got the solution due to pandas limitation it was truncating the data now it's working

Comment: df['value']=df['value'].apply(lambda x:{:.10f}.format(x))

Comment: This piece of code worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Using the `float_format` parameter will change displayed precision. However, the underlying `numpy.float64` value will be rounded / truncated anyway.

In order to load the decimal values w/o truncated as strings instead, then convert the column to `Decimal` type.

```py
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal
pd.options.display.float_format="{:.10f}".format
df=pd.read_csv(r"d:/temp/num.csv")
print(df)
print(type(df['Value'][1]))
print('-'*10)
df = pd.read_csv(r"d:/temp/num.csv", dtype={'Value': str})
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(Decimal)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
print(type(df['Value'][1]))
```

**Output**

```
                  Value                                           
0 1014541696.4299999475                                           
1 4553059826.7899999619                                           
<class 'numpy.float64'>                                           
----------                                                        
                  Value                                           
0  1014541696.430000072                                           
1  4553059826.790000215                                           
Value    object                                                   
dtype: object                                                     
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```